# Adding Header Search Path when trying to incorportate GPUImage in my xcode project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, video-capture, gpuimage

I am trying to add the GPUImage framework/library according to this:

github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

and I am stuck at the point of setting the Header Search Path. I tried setting a path but when I tried importing`#import "GPUImage.h"` I got an error saying it is not found. Maybe I put in the wrong path? I'm confused about what I should do because I have never used this before (very new to programming). Any  help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dont drag and drop the framework. Try adding files by right clicking instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suggest you use cocoapods. It handles gracefully library dependencies and GPUImage is present there.

cocoapods.org

It is also fairly easy to install and use

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're developing using Xcode 6, you might look at using the new framework support present in iOS 8 (and back to iOS 7, near as I can tell). The project has a true iOS framework that eliminates the need for setting paths to headers, like static libraries require. See the "Adding this as a framework (module) to your Mac or iOS project" section of the instructions for how to use this.

If you're targeting an older version of iOS and/or using an older version of Xcode, you'll need to set the Header Search Paths value in your build settings to be the path to where you installed GPUImage from where your application resides. For example, the sample applications in the examples/iOS directory use a path of

```
../../../framework
```

The .. elements in that tell it to step one directory back from the location of your application project. Since the examples reside in `GPUImage/examples/iOS/[project]`, the above relative path leads to `GPUImage/framework`. If you placed your project and GPUImage in the same encompassing directory, you might use

```
../GPUImage/framework
```

instead.

In that path setting, make sure you set the option on the right to "recursive" as well.

Use the sample applications as templates, and compare how they are set up to your application to find areas where you might have deviated from the listed setup instructions. About the hardest part of those instructions is getting the relative path right.